# Vue.Js - Import components problem in App.Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, slider, shared-libraries, single-page-application, vueperslides

I have a problem with my VUE js project. I use the library VueperSlides and it's run correctly but my problem, is that the slider is imported in the components App.vue and it's displayed. I want to display the slider only in my Slider component.
I have a router link which runs correctly.

[This is the APP.VUE component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JGK.png)

[This the HomePage (I want to put away this slider )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUHUK.png)

[This is the Slider Vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MF54.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just import it on your HomePage.vue:

```
import { VueperSlides, VueperSlide } from "vueperslides";
import "vueperslides/dist/vueperslides.css";

export default {
  components: {
    VueperSlides,
    VueperSlide
  },

  // ...
}
```

Then use `vueper-slides` and `vueper-slide` components on your template.

Comment: Yes i did it , but when, i put away the slider in the app.vue component, it's disappear in the Slider.Vue component